# All occurrences of a regex expression in string

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have a string for example `std::string s = " Hello as=-(Hello) asd#Hello"` and a regex `std::regex r(".*Hello.*")`

How can I find out all the matches?

I Tried an iterator

```
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                            i != std::sregex_iterator();
                            ++i )
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m.str() << " at position " << m.position() << '\n';
    }
```

But it only shows one match.

Comment: You should remove `.*`, `std::regex r("Hello")`.

Comment: [This isn't C++-specific](https://regex101.com/r/nGA7B6/1). The regex has one match in the string.